# Use IMAP and POP3 at the same account

Tags: email, imap, pop3

I have always used POP3 with my notebook and GMAIL account. Now I will have 2 notebooks, one at work and one at home, and I would like my email to be sincronized. If I send an email in work I would like to have access to that same email at home. I am using windows live mail today, and I have RULES for the incomming emails (pop3). What do you suggest that I do to be able to achive what I've described? My first tought was to move to IMAP, but then I've read that it doesn't accept RULES.

The only place where I need to keep an updated store of the emails is home, so the mail reading in office would be temporary, but if I send an email from office, I would need that email to be stored in Sent Itens at home. Also the emails I've already read in office would need to marked as read in home.

So I've tought in using both pop3 at home and imap at office, but I don't think that would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP is the way to go; with POP3 you may lose mails on one of the machines, even if you leave them on the server for a few days. And all your Sent mail will be in one place too.

Mailclients have filtering rules as well, so you can still automatically move incoming mail to the right folder.